# how to get vlan id from vcenter using ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use below ansible module to get vlan_id information.

```
- name: Get all portgroups in dvswitch vDS
  vmware_dvs_portgroup_find:
    hostname: "{{ vsphere_host }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    dvswitch: 'test-123' --- dvswitch
    validate_certs: no
  with_items: "{{ dvswitch_list }}"
  register: test

- debug: msg="{{ test }}"
```

I am getting out in below format.

```
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "dvs_portgroups": [
                    {
                        "dvswitch": "test-123",
                        "name": "DPortGroup2",
                        "pvlan": false,
                        "trunk": false,
                        "vlan_id": "220"
                    },
                    {
                        "dvswitch": "test-123",
                        "name": "PP1",
                        "pvlan": false,
                        "trunk": false,
                        "vlan_id": "465"
                    },
                    {
                        "dvswitch": "test-123",
                        "name": "PP2",
                        "pvlan": false,
                        "trunk": false,
                        "vlan_id": "685"
                    },
```

I am using below debug msg to get vlan_id but some how it does not work.

```
- debug: msg="{{ item.vlan_id }}"
  with_items: "{{ test.results.dvs_portgroups }}"

ASK [role_vmware_datastore_size : debug] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.90.00]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'list object' has no attribute 'dvs_portgroups'"}
```

Comment: `results` is a list of individual results (i.e. one for each item in your `dvswitch_list`). Hence `results.dvs_portgroups` does not exist, but e.g. `results.0.dvs_portgroups` does (like all following indexes in the list of results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test.results` is the list of results for each item of the `with_items` of the `vmware_dvs_portgroup_find` task. Therefore you have to iterate over this list before accessing a field of each element.

If you want to iterate over all the `dvs_portgroups` of all the results, you can do that:

```yaml
- debug: msg="{{ item.vlan_id }}"
  with_items: "{{ test.results | map(attribute='dvs_portgroups') | flatten | list }}"
```

1. `map(attribute='dvs_portgroups')` is transforming the list of results into a list of the `dvs_portgroups` of each result
2. `| flatten` is transforming the list of lists (the `dvs_portgroups`) into a list of all elements of each lists
3. `| list` is transforming an iterator back to a list that can be interpreted by `with_items`

Answer (score 0):

above debug code is working fine. I am getting list of vlan_id. Just to add more details. I have 4 dvswich and getting vlan_id from all dvswtich. I want to make it format like each dvswitch name with there vlan_id.

```
test-123 -- dvswith name
220
221
222

test-456 -- dvswtich name
300
301
302
```

I am trying below way but its giving only one vlan_id from each dvswitch.

```
- name: Final VLAN Details
  set_fact:
    vlan_details: "{{ vlan_details | default([]) + [dict(name=item[0], size=item[1])] }}"
  loop: "{{ dvswitch | zip(vlan_id) | list }}"
  loop_control:
    label: " "
```